# Strange Behavior for Spring cache guava TTL config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, guava, spring-cache, google-guava-cache

I have following spring cache config:

```
spring.cache.guava.spec: expireAfterWrite=1s
```

Then I have test for it:

```
@Test
public void test_not_work() {
  callCachedMethod(..);
  sleep(2s);
  callCachedMethod(..);

  expect("real method called TWO times"); 
  // because cache should be expired after 1s
  // It DOESN'T work, real method only called once
}

@Test
public void test_works() {
  callCachedMethod(..);
  sleep(2s);
  callCachedMethod(..);
  sleep(2s);
  callCachedMethod(..);

  expect("real method called THREE times"); 
  // because cache should be expired after 1s
  // IT WORKS!!
}
```

can someone explain it?

Comment: For one, are you sure Guava is actually being used? Instead of pasting a test we have no chance to run, please share a project that reproduces the problem. That'll be much easier to explain what is going on.

Comment: please explain the problem more, you don't write the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Guava does not ensure the eviction of the values automatically when the timeout value expires.

Per its documentation [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#when-does-cleanup-happen):

> Caches built with CacheBuilder do not perform cleanup and evict values
>   "automatically," or instantly after a value expires, or anything of
>   the sort. Instead, it performs small amounts of maintenance during
>   write operations, or during occasional read operations if writes are
>   rare.

Comment: thanks, it explains a lot, but why it works with 3 times call of the cached method..

Comment: @Jaiwo99 it just happens to work as you expected in that case. You shall not rely on it.